# Detect the size of an image in HTML, using python

Tags: python, html, css, image

I'm trying to implement a similar functionality to Facebook's thumbnail preview. The idea is, a user enters the URL of a product, and selects the best image of that product.

In order to filter out images that obviously aren't a product, I want to filter them based on height and width > 150px.

I'm using python and BeautifulSoup to download the HTML and extract images, but can't find a way to gather the height or width when it is specified in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GD is a library that's been around for quite some time and it has a pretty easy interface to work with...Here's a [link to GD](http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/gd-ref.html)

See the "size" method to get width and height.

**EDIT**

Ah, how about this?

1. Parse the HTML content and retrieve URLs to the CSS file(s) and inline styles
2. Download the CSS file(s) and parse CSS files, in order, building a rule-set of the CSS rules.
3. Next, parse the rest of the HTML from Step 1, gathering IMG tags and if the IMG tag has a `class` name, look up the class name in your CSS rules and check for `width` or `height`.

Might sound a little complicated but I bet download a few CSS stylesheets is much lighter than downloading images and having to use an image library on the server-side.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I was hoping to find something that wouldn't require me to download and process each image, but I might have to settle.